# How do I toggle a class on an element within an un-ordered list on click of a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems pretty simple but refuses to work. I am trying to toggle a class within an un-ordered list. For instance, onclick of 'this' div with the class of profile, find the next instance of profile-text and add a class of show-text. If the user clicks on the second ul li it would remove the class and obviously re-assign it accordingly. Any help welcome.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt=""> 
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text">
          <h3>Anna Smith</h3>
          <h3>Consultant</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt=""> 
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text">
          <h3>John Smith</h3>
          <h3>Advisor</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function()   {

     $('.profile').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.profile-text').toggleClass('show-text');   
     });

  });
```

Comment: this is how I would do it: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/abza6360/

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/abza6360/)

```js
$(".profile").click(function() {
  $(".profile-text").removeClass("show-text");
  $(this).children(".profile-text").addClass("show-text");
});
```

```css
.show-text {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text show-text">
        <h3>Anna Smith</h3>
        <h3>Consultant</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text">
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <h3>Advisor</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [next](http://api.jquery.com/next) method finds the next sibling of the element.

You need to use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) method to find the element inside it ie. the children of the element or you may also use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children) method to find direct children of the element:

```
$('.profile').click(function() {
     $(this).find('.profile-text').toggleClass('show-text');   
});
```

Comment: I'm running Angular JS and some crazy CSS so although the JS fiddle is correct, and my other attempts when I isolate the code works, I am still experiencing bugs. Your answers are correct so good work and thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because `.next()` only finds siblings. The block you want to change the class on isn't a sibling of the block you clicked on.

You have to jump up to the `.parent()` (an `li`) of the block you clicked on, then find the same class within its `.siblings()`.

Here's an example that works...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.profile').click(function() {
    var $clicked_block = $(this);
    var class_to_find = '.' + $clicked_block.attr('class');
    var $siblings = $clicked_block.parent().siblings();

    $('.show-text').removeClass('show-text');

    $siblings.find(class_to_find).toggleClass('show-text');
  });
});
```

```css
.show-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text">
        <h3>Anna Smith</h3>
        <h3>Consultant</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="team.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="profile-text">
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <h3>Advisor</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I just changed the color to blue because I didn't have your original CSS, but you get the idea.